# what is -a and rotate command in ksh script

Tags: shell, ksh

i am very new to shell scripting and use man command for everything i am not able to understand.
This is my piece of code

```
$OUT="/try1.sh"
 if [ -a $OUT ]
 then
 rotate $OUT
 fi
```

what is -a doing and what is rotate command in ksh as there is no man entry for rotate in ksh.

Comment: try `which rotate` or `whence rotate` from your command line. If eiher return /path/to/file values, use `file /path/returned/by/which/to/rotate` and see if it is a script or an executable. If script, examine script to see what it is doing. Maybe it will even have useful comments;-). IF executable, search the web. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

`-a` is a conditional expression to `[[ ]]` or `[ ]`. It checks if a file exists same as `-e` but is an obsolete version.

As described:

```
A conditional expression is used with the [[ compound command to test attributes of files and to compare strings.  Field splitting and file name generation are not
performed on the words between [[ and ]].  Each expression can be constructed from one or more of the following unary or binary expressions:
string True, if string is not null.
-a file
       Same as -e below.  This is obsolete.

-e file
       True, if file exists.
```

As for your script, it checks if `/try1.sh` exists. Also I recommend having this format instead:

```
OUT="/try1.sh"          ## When assigning a value to a variable, don't include the dollar sign ($).
if [[ -a $OUT ]]; then  ## Use [[ ]]
    rotate "$OUT"       ## Quote your variables inside ""
fi
```